AddDependency Issue in IntelliJ Platform Plugin for Android Studio to Create New Project Template
I am trying to create a New Project Template in IntelliJ IDEA CE for Android Studio. I have started the project based on the this link https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-platform-plugin-template. I have successfully done so but I would like to add more dependencies to the default template the plugin is creating, not the plugin itself. Mainly want to add more compose dependencies at time of creation.
When I use the supplied method of addDependency(""), it fails to create the new project in Android Studio.
Creating the plugin in Intellij IDEA is fine and doesn't throw an error. It builds and installs without issue.
This is the version of Intellij IDEA I am using.

IntelliJ IDEA 2024.3.1 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-243.22562.145, built on December 9, 2024
Runtime version: 21.0.5+8-b631.28 amd64 (JCEF 122.1.9)
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Toolkit: sun.awt.windows.WToolkit
Windows 10.0
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Concurrent GC, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 2048M
Cores: 12
Registry:
ide.experimental.ui=true
i18n.locale=
llm.show.ai.promotion.window.on.start=false
Non-Bundled Plugins:
DevKit (243.22562.145)
org.jetbrains.android (243.22562.145)
Kotlin: 243.22562.145-IJ

This is the Android Studio

Android Studio Ladybug | 2024.2.1 Patch 3
Build #AI-242.23339.11.2421.12700392, built on November 22, 2024
Runtime version: 21.0.3+-12282718-b509.11 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Toolkit: sun.awt.windows.WToolkit
Windows 10.0
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Concurrent GC, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 2048M
Cores: 12
Registry:
ide.experimental.ui=true
i18n.locale=
Non-Bundled Plugins:
com.template.r2creations24.demo (2.0.2)

This is my projectRecipe
import com.android.tools.idea.wizard.template.ModuleTemplateData
import com.android.tools.idea.wizard.template.PackageName
import com.android.tools.idea.wizard.template.RecipeExecutor
import com.android.tools.idea.wizard.template.impl.activities.common.addAllKotlinDependencies
import com.android.tools.idea.wizard.template.impl.activities.common.addLifecycleDependencies
import com.android.tools.idea.wizard.template.impl.activities.common.addMaterial3Dependency
import com.android.tools.idea.wizard.template.impl.activities.common.generateManifest

private const val COMPOSE_BOM_VERSION = "2024.12.01"
private const val COMPOSE_KOTLIN_COMPILER_VERSION = "1.5.1"

fun RecipeExecutor.projectRecipe(
    moduleData: ModuleTemplateData,
    activityName: String,
    packageName: PackageName,
    defaultPreview : String,
    greeting : String,
    isLauncher : Boolean,
    canAddComposeDependencies: Boolean
) {
    addAllKotlinDependencies(moduleData)
    requireJavaVersion("1.8", true)
    setBuildFeature("compose", true)
    // Note: kotlinCompilerVersion default is declared in TaskManager.COMPOSE_KOTLIN_COMPILER_VERSION
    setComposeOptions(kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = COMPOSE_KOTLIN_COMPILER_VERSION)
    addMaterial3Dependency()
    addLifecycleDependencies(true)

    generateManifest(
        moduleData = moduleData,
        activityClass = activityName,
        activityThemeName = moduleData.themesData.main.name,
        packageName = packageName,
        isLauncher = isLauncher,
        hasNoActionBar = true,
        generateActivityTitle = true
    )

    applyPlugin("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.compose", "2.0.0")

    if (canAddComposeDependencies) {

        addDependency(mavenCoordinate = "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:+")
        addDependency(mavenCoordinate = "androidx.activity:activity-compose:+")
        addPlatformDependency(mavenCoordinate = "androidx.compose:compose-bom:$COMPOSE_BOM_VERSION")
        addPlatformDependency(mavenCoordinate = "androidx.compose:compose-bom:$COMPOSE_BOM_VERSION", configuration = "androidTestImplementation")

        val composeUiFormattedVersion = moduleData.let { ":$it" } ?: ""
        addDependency(mavenCoordinate = "androidx.compose.ui:ui$composeUiFormattedVersion")
        addDependency(mavenCoordinate = "androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics")
        addDependency(mavenCoordinate = "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling", configuration = "debugImplementation")
        addDependency(mavenCoordinate = "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview")
        addDependency(mavenCoordinate = "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest", configuration="debugImplementation")
        addDependency(mavenCoordinate = "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4", configuration="androidTestImplementation")

        addDependency(mavenCoordinate = "androidx.compose.material3:material3")
    }



    val themeName = "${moduleData.themesData.appName}Theme"

    val emptyActivity = emptyActivity(packageName, activityName, defaultPreview, greeting, themeName)
    val emptyActivityPath = moduleData.srcDir.resolve("$activityName.kt")
    save(emptyActivity, emptyActivityPath)
    open(emptyActivityPath)
}


The canAddComposeDependencies is a boolean that is checked ( or not ) on the New Application Screen in Android Studio. If it is not checked, everything works great. When I do check it, then the new application creation fails.
Just need to manually add new dependencies to new application creation. Doing it manually defeats the purpose of the project. If I move any single

addDependency()

out of the if statement. Then the new project fails to build.
Also looking back at it, the

addMaterial3Dependency()

doesn't add Material3 either but this doesn't throw an error or fails to build new application from template.
Here is the stacktrace

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void com.android.tools.idea.wizard.template.RecipeExecutor.addDependency$default(com.android.tools.idea.wizard.template.RecipeExecutor, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.io.File, boolean, int, java.lang.Object)'
at com.template.r2creations24.demo.emptyActivity.ProjectRecipeKt.projectRecipe(ProjectRecipe.kt:42)
at com.template.r2creations24.demo.emptyActivity.ProjectTemplateKt$projectTemplate$1$2.invoke(ProjectTemplate.kt:76)
at com.template.r2creations24.demo.emptyActivity.ProjectTemplateKt$projectTemplate$1$2.invoke(ProjectTemplate.kt:75)
at com.android.tools.idea.npw.model.NewTemplateRendererKt$doRender$1.run(NewTemplateRenderer.kt:98)
at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction$BuilderImpl.lambda$doRunWriteCommandAction$1(WriteCommandAction.java:147)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.AnyThreadWriteThreadingSupport.runWriteAction$lambda$4(AnyThreadWriteThreadingSupport.kt:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.AnyThreadWriteThreadingSupport.runWriteAction(AnyThreadWriteThreadingSupport.kt:328)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.AnyThreadWriteThreadingSupport.runWriteAction(AnyThreadWriteThreadingSupport.kt:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runWriteAction(ApplicationImpl.java:890)
at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction$BuilderImpl.lambda$doRunWriteCommandAction$2(WriteCommandAction.java:145)
at com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CoreCommandProcessor.executeCommand(CoreCommandProcessor.java:226)
at com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CoreCommandProcessor.executeCommand(CoreCommandProcessor.java:188)
at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction$BuilderImpl.doRunWriteCommandAction(WriteCommandAction.java:154)
at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction$BuilderImpl.lambda$run$0(WriteCommandAction.java:125)
at com.intellij.util.concurrency.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:27)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.runWithWritingAllowed(TransactionGuardImpl.java:229)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.access$100(TransactionGuardImpl.java:22)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl$1.run(TransactionGuardImpl.java:191)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.AnyThreadWriteThreadingSupport.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread$lambda$1(AnyThreadWriteThreadingSupport.kt:184)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.AnyThreadWriteThreadingSupport.runWriteIntentReadAction(AnyThreadWriteThreadingSupport.kt:84)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.AnyThreadWriteThreadingSupport.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(AnyThreadWriteThreadingSupport.kt:183)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:836)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$2.run(ApplicationImpl.java:424)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$1.run(LaterInvocator.java:101)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.AnyThreadWriteThreadingSupport.runWithImplicitRead(AnyThreadWriteThreadingSupport.kt:122)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runWithImplicitRead(ApplicationImpl.java:1162)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.doRun(FlushQueue.java:78)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.runNextEvent(FlushQueue.java:119)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.flushNow(FlushQueue.java:41)
at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.kt:696)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent$lambda$16(IdeEventQueue.kt:590)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.AnyThreadWriteThreadingSupport.runWithoutImplicitRead(AnyThreadWriteThreadingSupport.kt:117)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.kt:590)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.access$_dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.kt:73)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue$dispatchEvent$processEventRunnable$1$1$1$1.compute(IdeEventQueue.kt:357)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue$dispatchEvent$processEventRunnable$1$1$1$1.compute(IdeEventQueue.kt:356)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:843)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue$dispatchEvent$processEventRunnable$1$1$1.invoke(IdeEventQueue.kt:356)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue$dispatchEvent$processEventRunnable$1$1$1.invoke(IdeEventQueue.kt:351)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueueKt$performActivity$runnableWithWIL$1.invoke$lambda$0(IdeEventQueue.kt:1035)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.WriteIntentReadAction.lambda$run$0(WriteIntentReadAction.java:24)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.AnyThreadWriteThreadingSupport.runWriteIntentReadAction(AnyThreadWriteThreadingSupport.kt:84)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runWriteIntentReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:910)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.WriteIntentReadAction.compute(WriteIntentReadAction.java:55)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.WriteIntentReadAction.run(WriteIntentReadAction.java:23)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueueKt$performActivity$runnableWithWIL$1.invoke(IdeEventQueue.kt:1035)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueueKt$performActivity$runnableWithWIL$1.invoke(IdeEventQueue.kt:1035)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueueKt.performActivity$lambda$1(IdeEventQueue.kt:1036)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.performActivity(TransactionGuardImpl.java:106)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueueKt.performActivity(IdeEventQueue.kt:1036)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent$lambda$10(IdeEventQueue.kt:351)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.kt:397)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

I have changed various things in my code to be more close to various templates I have seen from various posts with no luck.
I saw this post https://cs.android.com/android-studio/platform/tools/base/+/mirror-goog-studio-main:wizard/template-impl/src/com/android/tools/idea/wizard/template/impl/activities/common/kotlinMacros.kt that shows the

addComposeDependencies()

I tried this method above but it doesn't exist. I can't import it. So I created my own extension function. The code in it is now just placed inside the canComposeDependency if statement. The stacktrace keeps going to the

addDependency()

failure.
Any help would be appreciated on how I can add more dependencies to new application template.
***********UPDATE
I have just tried the plugin in IntelliJ IDEA CE. It run perfectly fine. Exactly as expected. I am still having issues with the plugin in Android Studio. The same issue as stated above. It fails on the "addDependency()" method with NoSuchMethodError.
Anyone have any ideas?
I wonder if it has an issue with the Android plugin used in Android Studio. The one in my Android Studio is
org.jetbrains.android:242.23339.11
while my IntelliJ IDEA CE is using
org.jetbrains.android:243.22562.218
